# My about window wont open

Tags: c++, api, winapi, dialog

I have been at this for 5 hours believe it or not. I'm very stressed out because it just seems so basic and when I actually get a hold of all this resource stuff, making program will be a lot easier.

Heres my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
BOOL CALLBACK AboutDlgProc(HWND hwndDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam );

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    PSTR lpszCmdParam, int nCmdShow)
     {
     static char szAppName[] = "ErrorSample";
     HWND           hwnd;
     MSG            msg;    // Look how this struct is defined-see help/class notes NOW
     WNDCLASSEX     wndclass; 
     HWND           hwndDialogBox = NULL;
     HMENU  hMenu;

          wndclass.cbSize        = sizeof(wndclass);
          wndclass.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
          wndclass.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
          wndclass.cbClsExtra    = 0;
          wndclass.cbWndExtra    = 0;
          wndclass.hInstance     = hInstance;
          wndclass.hIcon         = LoadIcon (NULL, IDC_ICON);

          wndclass.hCursor       = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
          wndclass.hbrBackground = static_cast<HBRUSH>(GetStockObject (WHITE_BRUSH));
          wndclass.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
          wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;
          wndclass.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ERROR));

          RegisterClassEx (&wndclass);

          hMenu = LoadMenu(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(102));

     hwnd = CreateWindow (szAppName,         // window class name
                    "Trying my damndest",            // window caption
                    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,     // window style
                    CW_USEDEFAULT,           // initial x position
                    CW_USEDEFAULT,           // initial y position
                    CW_USEDEFAULT,           // initial x size
                    CW_USEDEFAULT,           // initial y size
                    NULL,                    // parent window handle
                    hMenu,                    // window menu handle
                    hInstance,               // program instance handle
                    NULL);                   // creation parameters


     ShowWindow (hwnd, nCmdShow);
     UpdateWindow (hwnd);

     while (GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
          {
          TranslateMessage (&msg);
          DispatchMessage (&msg);
          }
     return (int) msg.wParam;
     }

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, 
                          WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
     {
     static HINSTANCE    hInstance;

     switch (message)
         {

         case WM_CREATE:
             hInstance = ((LPCREATESTRUCT) lParam) ->hInstance;
             return 0;

         case WM_COMMAND:
             switch(LOWORD(wParam))
             {
             case ID_HELP_ABOUT:
                 DialogBox( hInstance, "AboutBox", hwnd, AboutDlgProc);
                 break;
             }

             return 0;

         case WM_DESTROY:
             PostQuitMessage(0);
             return 0;
         }

     return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
     }

BOOL CALLBACK AboutDlgProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDOK:
        case IDCANCEL:
            EndDialog(hDlg, 0);
            return TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

When I click my ID_HELP_ABOUT case statement in my WM_COMMAND in WndProc, nothing happens. It doesn't even go into my AboutDlgProc Function.

Resource.h

```
//{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}}
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated include file.
// Used by Practice.rc
//
#define DIALOG_BOX                      9
#define IDR_MENU1                       102
#define ID_HELP_ABOUT                   40001

// Next default values for new objects
// 
#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE        103
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         40002
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE         1001
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           101
#endif
#endif
```

.rc file

```
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource script.
//
#include "resource.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#include "afxres.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// English (United States) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""afxres.h""\r\n"
    "\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "\r\n"
    "\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Dialog
//

DIALOG_BOX DIALOGEX 32, 32, 309, 178
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_SYSMENU
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,198,157,50,14
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// DESIGNINFO
//

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
GUIDELINES DESIGNINFO
BEGIN
    DIALOG_BOX, DIALOG
    BEGIN
        LEFTMARGIN, 7
        RIGHTMARGIN, 302
        TOPMARGIN, 7
        BOTTOMMARGIN, 171
    END
END
#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Menu
//

IDR_MENU1 MENU
BEGIN
    MENUITEM "&File",                       0
    POPUP "&Help"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "&About",                      ID_HELP_ABOUT
    END
END

#endif    // English (United States) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

Help please! =)

Comment: So crazy thought: Check the return result of `DialogBox()`, and if (-1), call `GetLastError()` to find out why it failed. And please post your `resource.h` and project .rc file appended to your question. If there is an issue with those, it will be obvious.

Comment: Edited. Will try checking the return result right now

Comment: I got error 1814 from LastError() and it says that resource name not found.

Comment: You cut off the top of your .rc script chopping literally the one line I needed to see; the DIALOG declaration. Try again.

Comment: Welp I edited it again. Hopefully didn't goof anything up this time.

Comment: Terrific . See answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your dialog box invoke to this:

```
DialogBox( hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(DIALOG_BOX), hwnd, AboutDlgProc);
```

Comment: Something that simple. Thank you. Could you explain to me how you knew to use DIALOG_BOX? Instead of ID_HELP_ABOUT? Is it because the thing that was going to be open was that dialog box and my naming scheme is so terrible that I didn't notice?

Comment: The resource ID for your DIALOG is `DIALOG_BOX`, defined in your `resource.h` and included in your .rc file. I could have just as easily told you to change the resource declaration in the .rc file to be `AboutBox DIALOGBOX ... etc`, but that would have likely broken the visual studio integrated designer. I had to see if you (a) had a resource id for it in resource.h, and (b) it was properly used in the .rc file. It was yes to both, so the only thing left was NOT using it correctly on the invoke (which you weren't).

Comment: Thank you Craig. You should write a book ;). Petzold just isn't getting it done for me.

Comment: @JesseMoreland Thats one of the most seasoned books on base-level Windows API there is. Don't expect too much too fast, and follow his samples closely.

Comment: Thank you Craig. I'll keep at it!